# Adding form data to mysql database PHP and AJAX

Tags: ajax

I am wanting to have a form that will let me add names to my database without refreshing the form. I have been working on it but it does not seem to work. I am quite new at this so any help is appreciated.

For my index.html I have:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".submit").click(function() {
var name = $("#firstname").val();
var username = $("#lastname").val();

var dataString = 'firstname='+ firstname + 'lastname=' + lastname

if(firstname=='' || lastname=='')
{
$('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "join.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(){
$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>



<body>

<form method="post" name="form">
<ul><li>
<input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" />
</li><li>
<input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" />


</li></ul>
<div >
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
<span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
<span class="success" style="display:none"> Registration Successfully</span>
</div></form>
```

For join.php:

```
<?php
include("db.php");

if($_POST)
{
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['username'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO persons (firstname,lastname) VALUES('$firstname','$lastname')");
}

?>
```

and db.php:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "test";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

Comment: what response you are getting on the clicking of button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is mistake in code, 
you have coded

```
  var name = $("#firstname").val();
  var username = $("#lastname").val();
  var dataString = 'firstname='+ firstname + 'lastname=' + lastname
```

you have to used the variables **name and username** in **dataString** but you have written the id(s) of fields for first and last name. change either the variable name or variables used in dataString

corrected line is :

```
 var dataString = 'firstname='+ name + 'lastname=' + username
```

And

```
   $lastname=$_POST['username']; =>  $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
```